# Any user logins in my application with different-2 browsers or systems

Tags: asp.net

Any user logins in my application with different-2 browsers or systems. And he wants to change the password. Once he'll change his password then he must be log-out from all browser's and systems automatically without any performing action and click

Comment: simple answer is not possible

Comment: Great simple answer is not possible